# Creating a table in magento way

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to learn how to create a table using an example from a book but with no success.The module is there but the tables are not created.I can't find the error and i don't know how to debug it.
Is there a way to debug it?
Can someone point me if and where i am doing something wrong?
Thanks

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();



/**
 * Create Registry Type Table 
 *
 *
 */

$tableName = $installer->getTable('mdg_giftregistry/type');
// Check if the table already exists
if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
    $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('mdg_giftregistry/type'))
        ->addColumn('type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'identity'  => true,
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Type Id')
        ->addColumn('code', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 25, array(
            'nullable'  => true,
        ), 'Code')
        ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 250, array(
            'nullable'  => true,
        ), 'name')
        ->addColumn('description', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 250, array(
            'nullable'  => true,
        ), 'Description')
        ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null,
            array(
                'unsigned' => true,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => '0',
            ),
            'Store Id')
        ->addColumn('is_active', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '1',
        ), 'Is Active')
        ->setComment('Magento Developers Guide Type Table');
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
}
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check:

- Clear cache is enabled.
- Check core_resource table, if your module_setup record is same as of
  your module version defined in config.xml file, the installation
  script won't run. Either you have to delete the entry or run a
  upgrade script.

If that's not the case check if your setup file is getting called. If    not, then you need to check your config.xml. It should be someting    similar to:

```
<models>
    <giftregistry>
        <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Model</class>       
        <resourceModel>giftregistry_resource</resourceModel>
    </giftregistry>
    <giftregistry_resource>
         <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Resource</class>
         <entities>
               <type>
                    <table>your_table_name</table>
               </type>
         </entities>
    </giftregistry_resource>
</models>    

    <resources>
     <giftregistry_setup>
         <setup>
            <module>Mdg_Giftregistry</module>
            <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
         </setup>
         <connection>
              <use>core_setup</use>
         </connection>
      </giftregistry_setup>
    </resources>
```

well not tested it, but your config.xml should have similar code, here's a link that can help, if still not work
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources